# override "List" block but not working (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-list

I have overridden "List" block by following code

```
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product_list>NameSpace_ModuleName_Block_Product_List</product_list>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
```

Also I have added `"List.php"` under the same structure, but product list is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your config file properly here is the below example

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <namespace_modulename>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Block</class>
            </namespace_modulename>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Moreover check if the block is not overridden by some other module.

Comment: Yes suggestion worked. Actually it was overridden in another module, that's why it wasn't working.